# Set swipe area width for react-navigation DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm using the DrawerNavigator in an Expo app and while it works great, I don't see an option for customizing the width of the area in which swipes will trigger the drawer opening.

Currently it's a fairly small band, but I'd like it to be at least a little wider - maybe 20% of the screen (or even like Slack, which is 100%).

Is there a way to do this with this component?

Comment: Hi @jinglesthula I've checked the `DrawerNavigator` config throughly and right now they have hardcoded this `var MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE = 3;`, So I guess there is no way you can cusomize it.. btw what is your research..

Comment: Hmm, ok.  Maybe I'll submit a pull request and suggest making it customizable.  My research went as far as reading the docs and googling to see if I could find anyone talking about it.  I was hoping I'd missed it somehow and that it was supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At v5.0 this option called **edgewidth**, at v6.0 **swipeEdgeWidth**

Example (v5.0):

```
<Drawer.Navigator
   drawerStyle={{ width: '75%' }}
   edgeWidth={200}
>
...
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

For more info see:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/drawer-navigator#edgewidth